# Add frame to all the plots in pairplot

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization

I am doing a pairplot using Seaborn as shown in the figure.

```
sns.pairplot(dataframe, kind='scatter',diag_kind="kde",corner=True)
```

I would like to add a frame around each plot. Is this possible? I have been looking around and I haven't seen anyone do it before.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `grid_kws={"despine": False}`.